# Find and generate value for some range date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data in DateRange table:

```
-------------------------------------
DateID       FromDate      ToDate
-------------------------------------
  1          2015/03/21    2015/09/22
  2          2015/09/23    2016/09/21
  3          2016/09/22    2017/09/22
  4          2017/09/23    2018/09/22
  5          2018/09/23    2019/09/22
  6          2019/09/23    2020/09/21
  7          2020/09/22    2021/09/22
 ...
```

and this data in DateValue Table :

```
-------------------------
 ID   DateID   Value
-------------------------
 1      3        3
 2      6        5
```

This is the result I need:

```
-------------------------
 DateID     Value
-------------------------
   1          0
   2          0 
   3          3
   4          3
   5          3
   6          5
   7          5
   ...
```

If there is no data for range use 0 value and for between 2 DateId use same value and if it is last data value use it till end

Please assist with an SQL query. I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: It is not clear what is the role of `FromDate` and `ToDate` values. Should we just ignore them? Why did you include them in the question?

Comment: Value of Fromdate and ToDate is Fixed and genarate by Start and End of Persian Calandar Year  - All date are consecutive and DateId is Identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select DateRange.DateId, case when DateValue.Value is null
  then 
  isnull((select top 1 Value from DateValue where DateId < DateRange.DateId 
  and Value is not null order by DateId desc),0) else Value end as Value
  from DateRange left join
  DateValue
  on DateRange.DateId = DateValue.DateId
```

Comment: thanks but this generate 0 for DateId 4 and 5 and 7 - Value for DateID 4 and 5 must be 3 and Value for DateId 7 must be 5

Comment: Answer was updated check if you still have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

it is assumed that your `DateID` is in same ascending order as the `FromDate`

```
SELECT r.DateID, Value = COALESCE(v.Value, 0)
FROM   DateRange r
       OUTER APPLY
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 x.Value
           FROM   DateValue x
           WHERE  x.DateID >= r.DateID
           ORDER BY x.DateID
       ) v
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i generate mistake result

Answer (score 0):

use temp table for this issue
somethings like that :

```
select Dr.DateID,Dv.Value into #Temp from DateRange Dr left join DateValue Dv on Dr.DateID=Dv.DataId

update #Temp set Value = (select top 1 Values from #Temp t where T.DateID<#Temp.DateID And Value is not null order by DateId desc) where Value is null 

UPDATE #Temp SET Value=0 WHERE Value IS NULL



    select * from #Temp
```

i hope that does well

Comment: what's problem?

Comment: i edit your query and it work fine, for first data will return null value so i update them again